# Cygwin Perl Module " use Spreadsheet::Read qw(ReadData);" stopped working

Tags: perl

I've recently upgraded my Machine , thus installed Cygwin on new Latop 
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) , old release was "GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) "

Also Perl got updated from version v5.22.1 to v5.26.1 . Most of my script works but Excel based scripts stopped working.   Here is a basic example which is not working ..

```
use Spreadsheet::Read qw(ReadData);
my $book = ReadData ('simple.xlsx');
print 'A1: ' . $book->[1]{A1};
```

I'm getting an error Parser for XLSX is not installed at test.pl  line 2 .

What am I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably don't have any Perl dependencies any more. Install them from CPAN.

Comment: Modules (both core modules and modules you install from `cpan`) are typically installed in directories specific to a specific version of perl. When you upgrade perl, you need to reinstall your modules.

Comment: Thanks Guys ..I used " instmodsh " & option l on my old machine and compare with the new machine and installed all the pending Perl Modules and its working fine ...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install either `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` or `Spreadsheet::XLSX`.